# How to select a loop of faces

Tags: selection-tools, loop

[image][image]I am trying to select the loop of faces that you see partially lit all around the sphere. Please note that I am able to do that for all the other loops by clicking on alt+rmb. Whith these thinner sliceses (that i obtained by adding loop cuts). I have tried in any way also searched the web and videos, but wasn't able to find a way out.
Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 3):

you have two ways (each one is responsible in its case):

1- *use loop selection**: Go to *face-mode* by pressing <kbd>3</kbd> (or *vertex-mode* by pressing <kbd>1</kbd>); hold <<kbd>Alt</kbd> and click on one of perpendicular edges along the face-loop.

[image]

2- **use shortest path**: Go to *face-mode* by pressing <kbd>3</kbd> select one face. hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and select some other face and the shortest path would be selected. do this consecutively to select your desired faces.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but in case anyone else has this issue in the future:

Loop select with `alt+click` will choose which loop to select based on which edge the cursor is closest to.

To select smaller slices, hover the cursor over the shorter edges of the faces when selecting.

[image: loop selection]

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite as easy as selecting loops, but you can select one face, then ctrl-click another face in that same row part way around (to select everything between those two).  You can usually work your way around a sphere with ~3 clicks this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can also select these faces by going in side view (3 on numpad) then set she shading to wireframe with shift+z and then select the faces using box select (ctrl+b).

And also your issue may come from double vertices. To delete them you can use the "merge by distance" in 2.8+ and the "remove doubles" in 2.79-. you should then be able to select your face loops.